# Display simple product urls in magento 2 bundle selections

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, simple-product, product-urls, bundle

In a bundled product I would like to be able to show the product url from a simple product or the selected item within the bundled product as a "view item" link.

So when this is selected the user is able to view the simple product details via the link.

I have been looking and trying different code but cannot get this to show so I would say no need to place code in here as it does not work.

I am kind of new to the backend side of Magento 2 so hopefully someone can help, if you have a link on how to achieve would be great as well.